# What happens to an SQLite database upon recycle of IIS AppDomain

Tags: sql, asp.net, sqlite, iis

Since SQLite runs in-process, it must be recycled along with an IIS web service. But those services [start a new instance before the previous one terminates](https://serverfault.com/a/333948/147633)  is there a chance of the database getting corrupted or a request getting wrong data?

If not - how?

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite including file locking mechanism.  So your DB is safe to access, but the only issue is your DB could be locked by someone.  You can read [Using SQLite In Multi-Threaded Applications](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) for more detail.